# Words to array function

Tags: php

Is there a function to convert a group of words to an array in PHP? The goal of my code is to take an input date and to rearrange it. Would it be best simply to use "explode()"?

Answer (score 1):

yes. `explode()` is essentially what you need, then `implode()` to get it back into a string.

Answer (score 1):

A function you can use is `explode()`. Before PHP version 5.3.0 the function `split()` was also useful for this, but it's now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following?

`$date='2010-10-01'; // YYYY-MM-DD`

`$dateArray=explode('-',$date); print_r($dateArray);`

`$dateCattedAgain=implode('-',$dateArray); echo $dateCattedAgain;`

You can rearrange the year, month, and day bits as needed.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do in this specific situation would be to parse the date and then reformat it as needed. For example:

```
$d = date_parse('12-12-2009');
print_r($d);
```

Which yields:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2009
    [month] => 12
    [day] => 12
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

This will also help you catch invalid date ranges.